# Interpolating irregular data on a sphere

Tags: interpolation, spherical-harmonics

I am trying to interpolate irregular data $f(\theta, \phi)$ on a sphere and I have so far tried a scipy approach using Kd-Trees and inverse distance weighting, which works ok - however I was wondering if there is an open-source library for spherical interpolation.
I have come across the [SHTns](http://users.isterre.fr/nschaeff/SHTns/) library, which is suggested to be useful, but it's not immediately clear to me how to use it for interpolation purposes.

I was wondering if someone could please shed some light on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more searching I've managed to find what I was looking for. They are available on NETLIB as stripack and ssrfpack - fortran routines - that allow for spherical interpolation of irregular data using spherical splines.

There's also an alternative that uses [generalized Green's function for spherical surface splines in tension](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/wessel/sphspline/). The matlab code (and the associated paper) is available there, although it has GMT as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

On a basic search on Spherical Interpolation I found these:

- Graphics Math Template Library (GMTL)

Link: http://ggt.sourceforge.net/

> **How do I perform spherical interpolation with quaternions?**
>
> Use the slerp function. You need an origin quaternion, a target quaternion, and an interpolation amount between 0 and 1. The following example interpolated halfway between the origin and target quaternions. Note that the interpolation path follows the shortest length arc around a sphere.

```
  gmtl::Quatf resultQuat, originQuat, targetQuat;
  float amount = 0.5;

  gmtl::slerp( resultQuat, amount, originQuat, targetQuat );
```

> Source: http://ggt.sourceforge.net/html/gmtlfaq.html

- Example Code for Spherical Interpolation

Project Link: http://freesourcecode.net/cprojects/2275/Piecewise-Linear-Image-Denoising

C++ Link: http://freesourcecode.net/cprojects/2275/sourcecode/quaternion_demo.cpp

H Link: http://freesourcecode.net/cprojects/2275/sourcecode/quaternion_demo.h

- OpenGLDemoEngine:

Spherical Interpolation: http://gitlab.scss.tcd.ie/gv2/opengldemoengine/blob/bc0b7ab4f7e4fc287dd7905353bf4a783c05813d/Dependencies/assimp--3.0.1270/include/assimp/quaternion.h

LINK: http://gitlab.scss.tcd.ie/gv2/opengldemoengine